# Rails Table with where clause and order by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, sql-order-by, where-clause

I am fairly new to rails so I am not familiar with the SQL for rails.
I have the following non availability table and I want to only display the ones where the date is today or greater. I also what to order them by the employee_id.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 right">
      <% @non_availabilities = NonAvailability.all %>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-md-2">Employee</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Date</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Time</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Reason</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @non_availabilities.each do |non_availability| %>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.employee.full_name %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.date %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.time %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.reason %></td></tr>
      <% end %>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

What is the syntax for this solution?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! Do you mean displaying time when selected employee is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did for this is use the following code.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 right">
      <% @non_availabilities = NonAvailability.all %>
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-md-2">Employee</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Date</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Time</th>
          <th class="col-md-2">Reason</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @non_availabilities.each do |non_availability| %>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.employee.full_name %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.date %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.time %></td>
        <td class="col-md-2"><%= non_availability.reason %></td></tr>
      <% end %>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Since OP completely rewrote the question to ask a completely different question, this answer doesn't really make sense anymore. But it does answer [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52651259/revisions).**

Assuming there is some connection between the `employee` property on the `Scheduling` model and the `employee_name` on the `Nonavailability` model, you should be able to create an association between the two through your `Employee` model (assuming it too is a model; if not, you might need to be more explicit about your DB structure).

Depending on how things are set up, I would assume a [`has_many :through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association would be what you're looking for. Then you would be able to call `@scheduling_instance.nonavailabilities` in the `scheduling` views to access the `nonavailability` info.

Comment: Yeah. Assuming that the `employee` and `employee_name` properties referenced above are both accessible through an `Employee` model.